# What is the return value if we dont return anything from a non void return typed function in c++?[Experimental]

Tags: c++

I have observed that if I don’t return any value from an empty function with an `int` return type is `1`. But in the below case it is showing `4 3 2` as o/p(is this the value of the static variable `si` getting printed here? if I print `si` I will get o/p as 2 3 4, in the reverse of what I get now. is there something to do with the function's stack push and pop here in this case?). Also I observed that if I use float as return type then it prints `nan nan nan` as o/p. Is this behavior compiler dependant (I have tried with both gcc and devcpp, observed the same)? What is actually going on here? Please share your thoughts on this.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int f(int i){
     static int si = i;
     si = si + i;
     ///return si;
}

int main(){
    cout<<f(1)<<" "<<f(1)<<" "<<f(1);
    //cout<<" "<<f(1);    //if I uncomment this line then the o/p is: 4 3 2 5, it looks like it's printing the value of si.
}
```

It looks like the behavior of `cout` causing the reverse printing of static variable `si`'s value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is undefined behaviour. You have to return something from a non-void function<sup>*</sup>

From **§ 6.6.3  The return statement [stmt.return]**

> Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no
>   value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning
>   function.

<sup>* The `main()` function has an implicit `return 0` so it is not necessary to explicitly return. This is a special case.</sup>

Comment: If it's undefined then why I am getting the same o/p from different compilers for every execution of same piece of the code as above? Does it mean there is something defined which is of `type undefined`?

Comment: @Renuka It is undefined behaviour. Anything can happen.

Comment: okay thanks juanchopanza
 :)

Comment: @Renuka I get `4 3 2` as well. Maybe it is the value of si laying around in some register, and the function calls are being executed from right to left.. But why does any of this matter?

Comment: @Leonardo, here I am trying to understand more about the behavior which I have observed from the above piece of code even if it’s undefined.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* means the implementation can do anything in response to it and still be compliant with the standard. **Anything**. It could erase your hard drive instead of printing `4 3 2`, and that would be OK as far as the standard is concerned.