# Dev C++ keeps crashing when I run this code. I cannot figure out why

Tags: c++, string, function, class, operators

I do not know whats going on. The program seemed to work fine on visual studio. Maybe I got something wrong and I cant spot it.. Please someone help me out with this one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;
class Aokiji
{
private:
    string name1;
    string name2;
public:
    string setName(string x)
    {
        name1=x;
    }
    string getName()
    {
        return name1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Aokiji Grapes;
    Grapes.setName("I got it!");
    cout<< Grapes.getName()<< endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Describe the crash.   Is it a SegFault?  What does a debugger tell you about the crash?

Comment: It works fine in visual studio, but doesn't work in what?

Comment: getName() should be const

Comment: possible duplicate of [If a function returns no value, with a valid return type, is it okay to for the compiler to throw garbage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9936011/if-a-function-returns-no-value-with-a-valid-return-type-is-it-okay-to-for-the)

Answer (score 4):

Your setName() function doesn't return anything, but it's supposed to return a std::string.  You need to return a value, or make the setName() function void (which is probably what it should be)

Comment: But he's not using the return value, so could it cause a crash?

Comment: @ooga Function doesn't know if you use the return value or not.

Comment: @ooga - If that function is silently returning 0 or an integer, then that is a cause of a segmentation fault.  Try to assign an integer to a std::string, and you will see what I mean.

Comment: @NeilKirk I know, but the fact is that he doesn't use it. Maybe it's some kind of "undefined behavior" if the function doesn't return a value when it says it will, even if you don't use it. I don't know.

Comment: It is undefined behavior. I'm surprised it compiles. A function with a return value requires at least one return statement on some compilers.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see. Interesting.

Comment: Can confirm.  What is probably happening is during the malformed string's destructor, bad stuff is happening.  How did this code compile?

Comment: Then the OP's main problem is that his warning level is not set high enough because his compiler should have warned him about this!

Comment: I am surprised that this is UB. GCC does not even raise an error, it only raises a warning if -Wreturn-type is set. Also, I have never seen a segfault because of that. Anyone could point out where it is UB in the standard?

Comment: Don't know if this is standard or not. Don't have the ANSI docs in front of me right now. However, if there is any hint of an integer being returned, then std::string constructor will try and construct one using the `const char*` overload, thus causing bad things to happen.

Comment: @qdii See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23043042/what-is-the-return-value-if-we-dont-return-anything-from-a-non-void-return-typed/23043061#23043061

Comment: @qdii: C++11 6.6.3/4 "Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in **undefined behavior** in a value-returning function" - so yes a crash is fine even if the return value isn't used.

Comment: @qdii: For completeness, note that C is different in this regard. From C99 6.9.1/12: "If the } that terminates a function is reached, **and the value of the function call is used by the caller**, the behavior is undefined"

Comment: This has fixed the problem, thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed at by PaulMacKenzie, the problem is the missing return statement. This is the reason why using C++, one should always use the `-Werror=return-type` flag to ensure that functions do not miss return statements.

I'm amazed C++ allows that, actually. The only case I think where it is legitimate that a function could miss a return statement is if it is supposed to return something, but instead it throws an exception and therefore does not return. But that's a very narrow use case, and adding a dummy return statement in that case does not cost anything.

Answer (score 0):

Replace setName() method in your code by:

> ```
> void setName(string x)
> {
>     name1 = x;
> }
> ```

And you need return 0; in int main() .